# Not able to load my 3D object(GLTF) at run time

Tags: java, android, sceneform

Not able to load my 3D object(GLTF) at runtime.  or i might not getting 3D object(Gltf) from server. . .
i'm trying to get 3D object  from a live server and try to load that object into my scenefoam. but i'm not able to load and show 3D object. when i try to load the object i got these error mention below my app is not crashing but still not able to load the 3D model (GLTF). Or i need to get some special-type of Url or anything else from my server when getting object from api ?

this is my code (java )

///ARObjectActivity.java

```
public class ARObjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private ArFragment arFragment;
private String Asset_3D = "";
String imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a_r_object);

    arFragment=(ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

    WebServiceFactory.getInstance().getARObject(2).enqueue(new Callback<ARObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ARObject> call, Response<ARObject> response) {
            if (response.body().getFlag() ==1){

                Asset_3D = response.body().getFILES().getFilePath();

                imageUri = "http://abc.example.pk"+Asset_3D;

                Log.e("3dObject",imageUri );

                arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) ->
                        placeModel(hitResult.createAnchor()));


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ARObject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}

private void placeModel(Anchor anchor) {

    Toast.makeText(this, ""+imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                ModelRenderable.builder()
                        .setSource(ARObjectActivity.this, RenderableSource.builder()
                                        .setSource(ARObjectActivity.this,
                                                Uri.parse(imageUri),
                                                RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                                        .setScale(0.5f)
                                        .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
                                        .build()
                        )
                        .setRegistryId(Asset_3D)
                        .build()
                        .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNoteToScene(modelRenderable,anchor))
                        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ARObjectActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage()).show();
                            return null;

                        });
            }


}

private void addNoteToScene(ModelRenderable modelRenderable, Anchor anchor) {
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode();
    anchorNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);


}
```

}

ARObject.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.ARObjectActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/arFragment"
    android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

these are the errors i got in my logcat

```
 2020-03-28 17:40:32.929 7301-7301/com.adroit.asle E/native: hit_test.cc:381 generic::internal: No 
point hit.
2020-03-28 17:40:32.953 7301-7980/com.adroit.asle E/ModelRenderable: Unable to load Renderable 
registryId='/CONTENT/PRODUCT/MODELS/model23329.gltf'
 java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://abc.example.pk/CONTENT/PRODUCT/MODELS/model23329.gltf
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.SceneformBufferUtils.inputStreamToByteBuffer(SourceFile:48)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.
lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask
(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:118)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.
-$$Lambda$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask$0DkaOpfpmr8DYlbaxWogZtUpKTw.get(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1625)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://abc.example.pk/CONTENT/PRODUCT/MODELS/model23329.gltf
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.downloadUri(Unknown Source:26)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.call(Unknown Source:53)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.call(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.SceneformBufferUtils.inputStreamToByteBuffer(SourceFile:42)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.
lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$LoadRen derableFromSfbTask(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:118) 
    at 
com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.
-$$Lambda$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask$0DkaOpfpmr8DYlbaxWogZtUpKTw.get(Unknown Source:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1625) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://abc.example.pk/CONTENT/PRODUCT/MODELS/model23329.gltf
    at 
 com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.LoadHelper
.lambda$remoteUriToInputStreamCreator$3$LoadHelper(SourceFile:124)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.c.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.downloadUri(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.call(Unknown Source:53) 
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.assets.RenderableSource.call(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.SceneformBufferUtils.inputStreamToByteBuffer(SourceFile:42) 
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask
.lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask
(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:118) 
    at 
 com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.
-$$Lambda$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask$0DkaOpfpmr8DYlbaxWogZtUpKTw.get(Unknown Source:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1625) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-03-28 17:40:32.962 7301-7301/com.adroit.asle E/native: hit_test.cc:381 generic::internal: No 
point hit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error logcat speaks itself. There is no file

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://abc.example.pk/CONTENT/PRODUCT/MODELS/model23329.gltf
```

AFAIK there is no need some special-type of Url as long as the url is legit. Try hardcoded your `imageUri` to `https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/raw/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf` and see what happen i guess. (Source: [Load 3D models at runtime](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/create-renderables#load_3d_models_at_runtime))

Comment: Thanks for your reply buddy. le me check

Comment: why i'm not getting the gitf object file in an appropriate way  to show my Object as the given link worked for me. should my backend developer need to do something in his serverside to send me a gltf file in a specific way ?

Comment: I assume the `http://abc.example.pk/...` is fake link for the purpose of privacy to this question. with your REAL link as far as i know if you can open/read it like you open the `Duck.gltf` which show something like JSON then there is no problem (maybe will different with .gltf exporter from different 3D engine, i don't really know 3D Design). Maybe on your serverside there is some kind of permission / security that makes the file not readable/accessable?

Comment: u r exact what i'm facing right now the problem is i'm not getting the file from the server. . 
i told my developer to check with baseUrl to get the file which he is send me in a response and bang. server is banning that file due to some unknown reason but now i'm clear about my problem. thankyou so much for ur help. other wise i'll still thinking about my code that there is a bug in my code :) (Y)